# MDL grid on Desktop and Horizontal Scroller on Mobile

Tags: mobile

I've started looking into MDL (https://getmdl.io) and after reading this article (https://www.nngroup.com/articles/horizontal-scrolling/) I decided it's a bad idea to use horizontal scrolling on the desktop.

What I'd really like to achieve is to display a grid on the desktop where cards overflow naturally, but on mobile change it to display all the cards on a single line and become a horizontal scroller like you see in many mobile apps (e.g. Google Play Movies).

If it is not possible, please explain how I can achieve horizontal scrolling on mobile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any updates on this? Stuck with the same problem